# Inverse Moments of a Non-Central Chi-Square Distribution

Tags: r

I want to compute inverse moments and truncated inverse moments of a non-central chi-square distribution in R. How can I do that in R?

Suppose X follows the non-central chi-square distribution with degrees of freedom "k" and non-centrality parameter "t". My problem is to numerically compute the following expectations for various values of "t" so I can simulate the risk of James-Stein type estimators.

```
(i)   E[X^(-1)] and E[X^(-2)]
(ii)  E[X^(-1)I(A)] where I(A) is an indicator function of set A
(iii) E[1-c{X^(-2)}I(A)] where c is a constant.
```

Comment: If the purpose is simulation, you'd find `rchisq(n, df, ncp = 0)` useful. Just try `?rchisq` on R.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can numerically compute the expected value of a random variable by drawing a large number of samples and then averaging them. For instance, you could estimate the expected values of X^(-1) and X^(-2) with something like:

```
mean(rchisq(1000000, df=3, ncp=10)^-1)
# [1] 0.1152163
mean(rchisq(1000000, df=3, ncp=10)^-2)
# [1] 0.1371877
```

Comment: This was my first thought as well.  With that said there are always dangers associated with this.  If you aren't careful you might try to empirically estimate a quantity that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Paolella's [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=9SHARfvyiR4C&lpg=PA341&dq=intermediate%20probability%20non-central%20chi-square&pg=PA345#v=onepage&q=intermediate%20probability%20non-central%20chi-square&f=false), *Intermediate Probability* gives the moments of the non-central chi-square to various powers. See equation (10.10). You can find R code for these in the [*sadists* package](https://github.com/shabbychef/sadists/blob/5c28f5bb1ebea03c9aa637348a47a48dee0a8011/R/moments.r#L54-L72).